# Could the Oracle docs on JavaBean be wrong?

Tags: java, javabeans

In this [Oracle Doc on JavaBeans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html), we see:

```
public class FaceBean {
    private int mMouthWidth = 90;

    public int getMouthWidth() {
        return mMouthWidth;
    }

    public void setMouthWidth(int mw) {
        mMouthWidth = mw;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the property be `mouthWidth` instead?

Comment: As a matter of style, yes, it should be `mouthWidth`.  It is in no way required, though;  the whole point of JavaBeans is that the property accessor methods hide the implementation.  JavaBeans is also a pretty old specification, dating back to the 90s;  I assume the tutorial was also originally drafted at that time, when the evils of Hungarian notation were not nearly as well understood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, some programmers put m in front of their variables to show that they are "member" variables, which is what you are seeing here.